# Meaning behind the sentence “I can put up with him to live“

Tags: meaning

I have watched the film *Ip Man 2* in English a couple of days ago and I am still confused about the meaning of a specific sentence:

> I can't let the foreign devil look down on us. I can **put up with him to live** but can't let him insult Chinese martial arts.

Basically, the "foreign devil" is a boxer called Twister who is fighting against Ip Man. The person speaking is Master Hung.

So I know that to *put up with sth/sb* means to accept or tolerate something or someone, but I don't know what is meant by “to live“.

Does it mean that the person speaking can live with him but can't tolerate that he insults Chinese martial arts?

I have already looked at example sentences but “to put up with sth/sb“ has never been followed by  “to + verb“.

**Edit**: The whole context would go like this:

> I can't let the foreign devil look down on us. I can put up with him to live but can't let him insult Chinese martial arts.

Basically, the foreign devil is a boxer called Twister who is fighting against ip man. The person speaking is master hung. So master hung says: “I can't let Twister look down on us. I can put up with him to live but can't let him insult Chinese martial arts."

Comment: This looks very mysterious to me. We'd need more context around the quote to know what's meant here.

Answer (score 2):

Master Hung (or the screenwriter) is not a native English speaker.  He probably means "I can put up with his living, but..." (I can allow him to live, but ...); but the normal interpretation would be "I can put up with him in order to live, *but ..." (I can tolerate him so that he won't kill me, *but ...).  {The 'but's don't make much sense that way.}

Comment: I agree; it looks to me like the English was poorly-translated.